# Ordering array from PHP called by AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing this now:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'full_db.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {col_name: firstSel},
        success: function(data) {    
         var full_options = [];
          $.each(data, function (i, data) {
         full_options.push(data.age);
        full_options.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.age - b.age;
     });

     $('#second_select').append("<option>" + data.age + "</option>");
  });
}
});
```

This appends all of the distinct ages to my select (`second_select`) and if I console log `full_options`
I get this:

```
["55", "98", "34", "30", "45", "29", "26", "22", "37", "42", "32", "33", "36", "35", "56", "46", "25", "54", "86"]
```

I'm looking to get this in ascending order (e.g.: 22, 25, 26, 29,...).

What am I doing wrong here that I'm getting an unordered array?

Comment: If you are doing a DB call do the sorting in the `SELECT statement`. `ORDER BY column_name DESC`

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you are sorting them in PHP, why the extra sort in JS after the AJAX call?

Comment: 22,25,26 is not `descending` order. Please correct this

Comment: `what am i doing wrong` .. your sort function assumes an array of objects with property `age` but when you push `data.age` into array you are only pushing in a primitive value not an object

Comment: @PanamaJack I have no idea in the world why I didn't do this in the first place. I guess that's the penalty for being new to PHP (and JS, etc, etc). Your fix was simple and solved the problem. Can you put down as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @jonmrich It happens. Sure thing, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm providing an answer for the comment I made.

If you are doing a DB call do the sorting in the query

```
SELECT * from table ORDER BY column_name DESC
```

Comment: No idea how I missed this...thanks for the simple solution, which obviously fixes all my sorting problems at once.

Answer (score 1):

You better sort the data in PHP or MySQL before it gets into JavaScript.
But if you wish, you can surely sort arrays in JavaScript.

```
full_options.sort(); // ascending order [1,2,3]
```

Or,

```
full_options.sort();
full_options.reverse(); // descending order [3,2,1]
```

Here is what you performing:

```
full_options.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.age - b.age;
});
```

This is a more complex way to do it, it sorts ascending. 
But you perform it in wrong place.
You code should be:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'full_db.php',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     data: {col_name: firstSel},
     success: function(data) 
     {    
          var full_options = [];
          $.each(data, function (i, data) 
          {
              full_options.push(data.age); 
              $('#second_select').append("<option>" + data.age + "</option>");
          });
          full_options.sort();
     }
});
```